# How come nobody noticed Chapra's slave brand at the tournament?

Tags: buddha

In the first book of Osamu Tezuka's "Buddha", one of the main characters is Chapra, a shudra (member of the slave caste).
He is marked as a shudra by a brand on his foot; at one point he even considers chopping of his foot to get rid of this mark.

Later on, Chapra manages to pretend that he is a member of the much higher Kshatriya (warrior) caste.

During this time, he participates in a tournament. The tournament takes several pages, and it is clearly shown that his feet are **not** covered.

So how come nobody at the tournament noticed his mark? Did Tezuka overlook this, or did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

Calling on the [Willing suspension of disbelief](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WillingSuspensionOfDisbelief) trope.

I think it was just an overlooked detail when it comes down to it.

To add on to this, as I recently reread Buddha, there are plenty of other spots where they should have noticed his brand. Like the time he was hung upside down after bragging during training. There really is no explanation. Maybe he came up with some way to mask it, like body paint, or something.